# Lazy loading Pattern with Typescript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, typescript, lazy-loading

So with C# and other languages where you have a get and set assessor on properties, it's quite simple to build a lazy loading pattern.

I only recently started playing with Type Script and I'm trying to achieve something the same. I'm loading a Poco with most of it's properties via a Ajax Call. The problem can be described below:

```
export interface IDeferredObject<T> {
    HasLoaded: boolean;
    DeferredURI: string;         
}

export class Library{        

    LibraryName: string;
    Books: IDeferredObject<Book[]>;        
}   

export class Book {
    Title: string;
    UniqueNumber: number;
}



window.onload = () => {
    //Instantiate new Library
    var lib = new Library();

    //Set some properties
    lib.LibraryName = "Some Library";

    //Set the Deferred URI Rest EndPoint
    lib.Books.DeferredURI = "http://somerestendpoint";
    lib.Books.HasLoaded;      



    //Something will trigger a  GET to lib.Books which then needs to load using the Deferred Uri       

};
```

Couple of questions: 
I

- Is a Interface even the right thing to use here?
- I'd like to trigger a Load action when something accesses the Library Books Property. Is this even possible?

I know it's quite an open question, just looking for some guidance on how to build that pattern.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Books` could be declared as a property(see [get and set in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12850536/1314859)) and in its getter you can start an ajax call. The only issue is that you cannot know when the ajax call will return and you don't want to block the code execution while value for `Books` is loading. You can use [promise](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) to solve your problem. The following code is using [JQuery Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) which is returned by `$.ajax` call (since 1.5 version).

One change - `HasLoaded` and `DeferredURI`. They should reside in "loader class" i.e. `Library` because in my example `Library` class is responsible for data retrieval.

```
export class Library {
    private _loadedBooks: Book[];
    public get Books(): any {
        var result: any = null;
        // Check first if we've already loaded values from remote source and immediately resolve deferred object with a cached value as a result
        if(this.HasLoaded) {
            result = $.Deferred();
            result.resolve(this._loadedBooks);
        }
        else {
            // Initiate ajax call and when it is finished cache the value in a private field
            result = $.ajax(this.DeferredURI)
                          .done((values) => {
                              this.HasLoaded = true;
                              this._loadedBooks = values; 
                          });
        }
        return result;
   }
}
```

Then code consumer would use `Books` as following:

```
var library = new Library();
library.Books.done((books: Book[]) => {
    // do whatever you need with books collection
});
```

For me this design is counter intuitive and user of this code would not expect the `Books` field/property to return a deferred object. So I would suggest to change it to method, something like `loadBooksAsync()`. This name would indicate that the code inside this method is asynchronous and hinting that return value is a deferred object which value would be available somewhere later.

Answer (score 2):

> Is an Interface even the right thing to use here?

**Yes**, using interfaces simplifies the coupling problems also in `TypeScript`

See also: [Programmers: Why are interfaces useful?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/108240/why-are-interfaces-useful)

> I'd like to trigger a Load action when something accesses the Library Books Property. Is this even possible?

**Yes**, it is possible to implement any loading pattern you like. `TypeScript` is just `JavaScript` when it comes to code loading.

**But**, for small to medium sized applications the loading is usually not addressed at `TypeScript` level but is rather handled by the `module loader` and `script bundler`.

Supporting statement:

> https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js#deprecation-notice
>
> **Deprecation Notice**
>
> ...The authors of yepnope feel that the front-end community now offers better software for loading scripts, as well as conditionally loading scripts. None of the APIs for these new tools are quite as easy as yepnope, but we assure you that it's probably worth your while. We don't officially endorse any replacement, however we strongly suggest you follow an approach using modules, and then package up your application using require.js, webpack, browserify, or one of the many other excellent **dependency managed** build tools...

See also:

- [Stack Overflow: How do AMD loaders work under the hood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117935/how-do-amd-loaders-work-under-the-hood)
- [Stack Overflow: When to use Requirejs and when to use bundled javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232848/when-to-use-requirejs-and-when-to-use-bundled-javascript)
- [Programmers: Practices for organizing JavaScript AMD imports](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260272/practices-for-organizing-javascript-amd-imports)