# How can you capture the result of a HTML script tag in a variable?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, amd

I have been reading about [AMD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) and implementations like `requirejs`. Most of the resources covers the usage and API's.

But, when it comes to implementing this, how can you load a JavaScript file into a variable just like that? For example, you can see functions like this:

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
});

var jquery = require('./jquery');
```

From an API consumer's perspective, all I can understand is that the file `jquery.js`has magically become `$`, `jQuery` etc? How is that achieved?

Any examples would be helpful.

[How do AMD loaders work under the hood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117935/how-do-amd-loaders-work-under-the-hood) is a helpful read.

Edit: I think the `eval` answers below are nice because it actually is an `eval` problem in some ways. But I would like to know this from the perspective of an [AMD specs](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md) implementation.

Comment: Are you sure they need to have the contents of a file in a variable?

Comment: Eventually, "it" gets injected into functions as a single variable right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way `define` works under the hood is not by loading an <s>"HTML Script into a variable"</s>. Typically a normal script can have multiple variables so it doesn't make sense to capture the value a variable! The `eval` approaches can probably do something like that if needed. It captures all that is there in the JavaScript source code.

The real key in `AMD` is that the `define` API maps a **name** to a **function**. Whenever you `require` with that name, it would just call that function and return the value to you. This return value is expected to be the **module**. This is a *convention* that makes everything work!

In other words, AMD uses an interesting convention (design pattern) to ensure that we get a modularization effect in JavaScript code. It is one level of indirection. Instead of the normal style of "write your code and get it executed in the global scope" paradigm, you just write a function that returns a single value that captures all the things you want to expose as a module to the consumer!

Comment: Can anyone review this answer?

Answer (score 3):

You don't load a javascript file into a variable, this is instead done by things such as browserify or webpack. Javascript itself *can* do this, but these modules generate a single file containing all your code. By calling `require("file")`, you are calling browserify's function to load a file named "file" stored in the code.

An example of this can be if you have a module

```
function demoModule(){
    console.log("It works!");
}
module.exports = demoModule
```

This makes module.exports now contain the "entire" contents of the file

Browserify/webpack puts that into a function that returns the module.exports of that file

```js
function require(filename) {
    switch(filename){
        case "demofile":
            let module = {exports:{}}; ((module) => {
               function demoModule(){
                   console.log("It works!");
               }
               module.exports = demoModule
            })(module)
            return module.exports;
    }
};
    
require("demofile")();
```

Your file becomes a function that you can call with `require("demofile")` and it returns anything that was a module.export.

Comment: Performance is actually improved by having one big file instead of 20 files. Less HTTP requests make the page take less time to load while sacrificing lazy loading

Comment: So do you mean, some kind of compilation is involved to make this work? Also, if we make it a single file, how are things like lazy load going to be possible? It should be modular right?

Comment: The modularity is in your code, but after compiling it it gets put into functions all in one big file. Compilation is necessary. It is good practice anyway to run your code through something like babel so old browsers can use new JS features.

Answer (score 2):

You know how you can say `eval(alert("hello!"))` and it executes the code?

You can also:

```
var str = "hello!"
eval('alert("' + str + '");')
```

So the next step is to have a file that has your actual script in it:

```
var str = "hello"
alert(str)
```

then you can use a standard AJAX request to fetch that file into a variable, and you can `eval()` that variable.

Technically, `eval()` is considered evil - fraught with dangers - but there are other solutions (for example, injecting a script tag into the document body).  I just went with `eval()` here to make the explanation easier.

Comment: `eval` is interesting. But I wanted to know if this can be done better. Even in the case of `eval`, you still have to read the file as a string. Is that possible? I have only seen `script` which is kind of a magic.

Comment: Hmm...I guess I didn't understand what you were asking for, then.  Hopefully some of the other answers here will clear up your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Extending what theGleep said.

Something like this:

```
var str = "if (x == 5) {console.log('z is 42'); z = 42;} else z = 0;";

console.log('z is ', eval(str));
```

For more read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

But use `eval()` very cautiously and be absolutely sure about the pitfalls and drawbacks of `eval()`.

Don't use it unless it is the only option.

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) too.

Comment: Are you saying `AMD` implementations use `eval`?

Comment: @Nishant Nope. I did not say that.

Comment: Okay. The question was mainly about AMD(implementation)'s way of doing things. So I got confused.